# Jekyll markdown without any layout

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to add a `webfinger` file to Jekyll (under `.well-known/webfinger`) in a markdown file (e.g. `webfinger.md` with the path in the front-matter).

```
---
layout: null
permalink: /.well-known/webfinger
---
{
  "subject": "acct:blah@blah.com",
  "aliases": [
    "https://blah.com/@blah",
    "https://blah.com/users/blah"
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "http://webfinger.net/rel/profile-page",
      "type": "text/html",
      "href": "https://blah.com/@blah"
    },
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "type": "application/activity+json",
      "href": "https://blah.com/users/blah"
    },
    {
      "rel": "http://ostatus.org/schema/1.0/subscribe",
      "template": "https://mastodon.nz/authorize_interaction?uri={uri}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought that the html would spit out the raw JSON, but it is wrapped with a HTML `<p>` tag. Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just done the same thing only a few minutes ago. If you change the name of the file to `webfinger` without the `.md` extension, then it should work.

I made the change in https://github.com/mgriffin/mikegriffin/pull/51 and you can see the result at https://mikegriffin.ie/.well-known/webfinger but it downloads the file if you visit it through a browser for some reason...